# Unable to finde the correct namespace but the reference has been added?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-signature

I'm trying to sign XML files in my application so obviously I'll need the System.Security namespace. I added the reference to the project but the followig using directive doesn't work.

```
using System.Security.Xml;
```

It works fine in a demo console application where I implemented to algorithm just to see how it works but for some reason it is not recognized in my actual project.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: If the rquired references is added, you will able to seel the required `using`by pressing Ctrl+. is Visual Studio and look an the context menu.

Comment: What's the error reported by Visual Studio when you attempt a build?

Comment: The type or Namespace name "XML" doesn't exist in namespace 'System.Security' (missing any assembly reference?)

I did add the System.Security Reference though.

Comment: You need `System.Security.Xml` or `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

As well as adding the 'using' line within your C# file, you also need to add a Project Reference to a .NET dll, for instance System.Security.dll or maybe System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll

Comment: I did both, the Project reference to the .dll is there. That's why I'm confused.